# Create composite image in WP8

Tags: .net, image, windows-phone-8

I have four images in my gallery, and I'd like to combine them into single image in grid like structure

Images in my gallery:
[A] - A.jpg
[B] - B.jpg
[C] - C.jpg
[D] - D.jpg

Single image result.jpg:
[A][B]
[C][D]

How could I achieve this on Windows Phone 8 platform?

Comment: You can do so using WriteableBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a  with 2 columns and 2 rows and an  in each cell. 
You can then create a WriteableBitmap and render the grid onto it by passing the Grid and a Transform to the Render method. Then calling the Invalidate method to make it draw itself.

You can then save the WriteableBitmap to use it or save it to the MediaLibrary